# Java FileUtils - Avoid download of HTML

Tags: java, download, fileutils

So I have an issue with the Apache Commons IO library, with FileUtils.

My code :

```
URL songUrl = new URL(urlToDl);
newSon = new File("test.mp3");
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(songUrl, newSon);
```

The problem is that sometimes (it's really random) the mp3 file is actually the HTML page of the site. But sometimes it downloads the mp3 like it should be.

How to avoid FileUtils to download HTML page but only mp3 file ?

**EDIT :**
so basically I create the download link with their json API :
http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/?format=JSON&video=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i62Zjga8JOM
I take the "link" value and then use FileUtils copy url to file function.

Comment: By making sure that the URLs you access are correct. We can't fix your code that randomly fails, especially when you show 3 lines of it.

Comment: It's probably the server's decision anyway.

Comment: There are sites that despite of the URL that is shown don't really give direct access to the file. This is usually done so they can have some control over who is downloading the files.

If there is a direct download URL you should use it. Sometimes you can find it in the HTML that is returned sometimes the site will not allow direct download in any way.

Comment: Maybe they're trying to prevent you from scraping the site.

Comment: @Kayaman I edited my post, you can see the url making process.